# How to use Box_Sizing property in HTML

Tags: html

what are the methods of using of box-sizing property in HTML

How to use box-sizing property in HTML?

I try to make a website

Answer (score 1):

Adding the box-sizing rule when building a web page defines how the width and height of an element are displayed to users - i.e., will the border or padding be added (or not).

The box-sizing property can have two values: **content-box** or **border-box**.
But developers often use the `border-box`.

The **content-box** is the default value i.e., you do not need to set it. But the quirk of this is that it makes your view bigger than the width or height set.
So, if you set your element width to **50px**, the rendered view will be greater than **50px** because the width and border would get added to it also.

But with **border-box**, which is the recommended value to use, if you set the width of the element to 50px, the border and width will be added together to make the 50px. The border will not be added separately as we had for the *content-box*.

Now you can just target your whole HTML file using the universal sector (*) like so:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) W3Schools article to learn more about box-sizing